# iMessage Extension and In-App-purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, imessage

I'm trying to create an extension for iMessage with InApp-Purchase feature. basically I created an iMessage application which create two target.

- Your AppTarget
- MessageExtension

and each one has it's own bundle identifier. ( extension has a prefix of app ). now i am trying to create to in-app-purchase for my app.
My app target does not have in-App purchase capability to make it active but my extension has. In iTunes connect my app id is my app target. so i should define in-app purchase for that.

by end of the day when i am getting `SKProductsResponse` its empty and i guess because my product identifier has my app target prefix and not my extension prefix.
has anybody experience in implementing of in-app-purchase for iMessage-extension ?

Comment: did you found anything??? any tutorials??

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, this is working fine for me.

```
com.company.application -> Your application target bundle

com.company.application.extension -> Your iMessage target bundle

com.company.application.extension.purchase_id_1 -> In-App identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an iMessage app target if you have a host iOS app. Adding an iMessage extension target is enough. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500283/319589) answer, this might be the reason.