# In-app Purchases from iMessage app extension

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, imessage

I created an app that uses in-app purchases, I already have set up the in-app purchases on iTunes and I even tested it using a sandbox user and all of this is working perfectly.

now that I included an iMessage app extension, the same in-app purchase products return invalidProduct Id, but continues working well inside the main app.

could be because the bundle id?

```
mainapp: com.whatever.bundleid
app iMessage: com.whatever.bundleid.iMessage
iMessage extension: com.whatever.bundleid.iMessage.MessagesExtension
```

btw, i'm using the SwiftyStoreKit pod.

```
if let inappIndentifier = stickerPackage.inAppPurchaseId {
        SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([inappIndentifier]) { result in
            if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
                let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
                completion(true, priceString)
            } else if let _ = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
                completion(false, nil)
            } else {
                print("Error: \(result.error)")
                completion(false, nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made a huge mistake, instead of creating an iMessage extension, I've created an iMessage app extension.
Once I removed the "iMessage app" the in-app purchases started working correctly.

Comment: Where did you remove "iMessage app"?

Comment: I removed the target from the app.

Comment: Thanks @Ponja. Worked like a charm.