# In-app purchases won't load for MessageExtension

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, imessage-extension

In Xcode 11 I created standalone iMessage app File, New, Projects, iMessage App. Then I got two targets. AppName with product identifier: com.AppName, AppName MessagesExtension with product identifier: com.AppName.MessagesExtension and Enabled IAPs.

In App Store Connect I created new app My Apps, +, New App. Where I selected following bundle ID com.AppName.MessagesExtension and added IAP Features-In-App Purchases with product ID: Example.

Then I added in-app purchase Example to com.AppName.MessagesExtension, but when loading IAPs it says IAP not found.

I have tried to change product ID [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358743/imessage-extension-and-in-app-purchase) of IAP with no help.

IAP code is fully working in another app (not standalone iMessage app)!

Comment: Solved using link provided above.